# Expression Cannot Be Evalulated

Tags: mysql, windows, visual-c++

I have an in C++ and mySQL. It's working mostly, occasional the program breaks on this line.

```
my_ulonglong numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);
```

It says that it cannot be evalulated. Can anyone shed any light on this? Is it something to do with the records in the database? Any help is appreciated. I've been wrestling three days with this.
   (mysql_real_connect                                                                                                                                                           (conn,"urlock.db.5513143.hostedresource.com","urlock","Admin1234","urlock",0,NULL,0) !=0);
    char queryString[1024];
    sprintf(queryString, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblURLIP WHERE IP = '%s' AND IPStatus = '1' AND 
    IPMax   = '0' AND IPType ='3'", ipSrc == 0 ? "0" : ipSrc);

```
mysql_query(conn, queryString);
my_ulonglong i = 0;
res_set = mysql_store_result(conn);
my_ulonglong numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);
LEGIT = mysql_fetch_row(res_set);
```

This is the error that pops up first.
Unhandled exception at 0x57088ce4 in lsniff.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Comment: This is under the call stack when the app breaks                                                              >lsniff.exe!main(int _argc=1, char * * _argv=0x00251bf8)  Line 224 + 0x9 bytes C++
lsniff.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 278 + 0x19 bytes C
lsniff.exe!mainCRTStartup()  Line 189 C

Comment: And this is next to the line....res_set 0x00000000 {row_count=??? fields=??? data=??? ...}.

Comment: Could it be that the connection is timing out?

Answer (score 0):

The connection is timing out, when I move to a local database, I don't have the problem.